# Unable to update API with HttpHeader in ANGULAR4

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular2-services

I am trying to update element through POST method. No matter what I do I still have some problem and I am unable to edit an item.
 API requires to get information about encoding : Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 so I am sending it inside the options.

```
editSensor(sensor){
const body = {"sensor_UID": sensor.sensor_UID, "sensor_ID": sensor.sensor_ID, "sensor_Name": sensor.sensor_Name};
var options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' })};
this.http.post('http://172.22.20.112/api/sensor/update', body, options)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
  }, error => {
    console.log("problem with something");
  });
```

}

I am getting

> Failed to load http://172.22.20.112/api/sensor/update: Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

and

> OPTIONS http://172.22.20.112/api/sensor/update 404 (Not Found)

I am using HttpHeaders. It should be a better than old Headers right? What I am doing wrong here? I've spend last 3 hours trying to figure it out and there is just one problem after another.

I tried to edit through the Fiddler and it worked so problem is on my side.

Comment: Have you double checked that there is a handler in backend service for route /api/sensor/update?

Comment: @NishantShreshth The server is made in C# and it is tested with Postman and Fiddler without any problems.  So that should not be a problem

Comment: Does your api support CORS requests? I remember on my .NET APIs I used some Nuget package to enable CORS. The requests from fiddler/postman will pass by default, but not from your angular app.

Comment: Maybe change the way you are setting the headers. Have a look [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#headers).

Comment: @Alex It didn't. That solved the problem. API had to allow it on server side and I had to use use Allow-Control-Control-Origin: *. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try as below

```
import {Headers} from '@angular/http'
```

declare a variable in class as below

```
header:Headers
```

and in your method

```
this.header=new Headers();
this.header.append("Content-Type",'application/json; charset=UTF-8");

this.http.post('http://172.22.20.112/api/sensor/update', body, {headers:this.header})
```